# How to asynchronously load the pdf file while previewing?

Tags: pdf, sendfile

I am using pdfjs to preview the file and for path file i am using send_file as there is a restriction of having files in public folder. But its taking so much time to load it in the browser due to send_file. Is there any way to load that file asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Since the xref table in a PDF file is located at the end (unless the file is 'linearized') no you cannot load the file asynchronously.

Linearisation is also known as 'optimize for fast web view', now you know why.

Depending on what kind of access you have, you could potentially load the end of the file first, but that gets complicated.